# After find span in UI grid and click got failed: Element is no longer valid

Tags: protractor

I run function on UI-grid that all element in the grid are clickable.

```
it('Test1', function() {
    element.all(by.css('span.ft-grid-click')).each(function(elmt) {
            elmt.getText().then(function(txt) {
                if (txt == 'ORO_B_IN_002') {
                    elmt.click();
                    return;                     
                }                   
            })              
        })      
});
```

On screen the element clicked but I got this error:

Failed: Element is no longer valid (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information).

Help please.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a much better way to find an element by text Content: [`cssContainingText()`](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorBy.prototype.cssContainingText)

Here is, how it will look in your code:

```
it('Test1', function() {
    element(by.cssContainingText('span.ft-grid-click', 'ORO_B_IN_002')).click();
});
```

This should work for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! Work perfect!!